# Giving nested panels as argument to ItemsPanelTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

The following is an excerpt from my MainWindow.xaml. My question is about the part, where `ItemsPanel` is set via an `ItemsPanelTemplate`

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="2" dd:SmallDragDropHelper.IsDragDropEnhanced="true"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabCollection}" SelectedIndex="{Binding AktIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" TabStripPlacement="Top">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="titemplate"/>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="tctemplate"/>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <TabControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="true"></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemsPanel>
</TabControl>
```

I understand that it is simple and working to write a single panel type as argument/content of the tag `<ItemsPanelTemplate>`. But what I need/wish is to be able to write the following

```
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
            <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" IsItemsHost="true"></WrapPanel>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right">Add</Button>
            </DockPanel>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

The intention is, that the tabitem headers should be given to the wrap panel which is placed left in the `DockPanel` and a button should be shown in the same line flush right.

But it seems, it is impossible to give such a nested construction of panels as argument to `ItemsPanelTemplate` (at least it is not working as intended for me).

What is the right way to proceed here? (Googling gave me only examples with a single panel as argument to `ItemsPanelTemplate`). (I would prefer a solution using no C# code, only .xaml)

Comment: Set the TabControl's Template.

Comment: @Clemens Do you mean the `ControlTemplate` ? (WPF unleashed, p.430ff.) Am I not then responsible to give the total visual tree of the `TabControl` myself?

Comment: Yes, the Template property. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/tabcontrol-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Clemens I read through the example given in your link - it looks quite hefty, it seems as I suspected above, that I have to define the whole visual tree by myself. Or can I just give the very part that I am interested in, that is the line of tab headers which should get a button at its end?

Comment: @Clemens I did a brave copy and paste of the example now, although I feared it would probably not work, but on the contrary: It worked at the first start (even drag and drop of the tab headers was ok), which gives me some confidence not to be intimidated by such complexity. Nevertheless it would be nice, not having to replace the whole visual tree of the control.

Comment: @Clemens It worked out totally now: I could place the button as wished - many thanks for being the good wpf samaritan here at stackoverflow!